# UIWebview crashes app while scrolling image collection

Tags: ios, iphone, memory, uiwebview, crash

My application displays several html sites with a lot of images. When testing the app on iPad 3, iPad 4 or iPad Air it crashes with memory warnings while scrolling very fast.

To reproduce just make a simple App with an UIWebview:
I have a sample for you at http://www.blogboxapp.de/testUrzeit.txt.

Scroll very fast up and down.

```
htmlToLoad = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.blogboxapp.de/testUrzeit.txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlToLoad baseURL:nil];
```

I already tried solving with setting the NSURLCache like this. But it has no effect.

```
NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:8 * 1024 * 1024
                                                  diskCapacity:64 * 1024 * 1024
                                                         diskPath:@"nsurlcache"];

[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
```

Where should i look for a solution?

Best regards Bernhard

Comment: What is the error message that you get when it crashes????

Comment: First i get Memory warnings. 

After that it crashes with "Memory Pressure"

Comment: Ever get anywhere with this? I suspect the same thing is happening for me but I get  `delegate (webView:identifierForInitialRequest:fromDataSource:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: UITrackingRunLoopMode`